# Разбитие строки с помощью регулярных выражений, если она содержит экранированные символы

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка вида

> Protocol=(SNMP) Address=(\(test\))

Можно ли ее разбить на пары ключ\значение, что бы получилось^

> Protocol - SNMP;
>
> Adress - \(test\)

Основная проблема заключается в том, что разбиение идет по первому вхождению закрывающей скобки ")". Т.е на выходе получаю

> \(test\

Как допустить вхождение такого экранированного символа?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать [негативный просмотр вперёд](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4).

`(?!\))` - проверяем, нет ли впереди закрывающей скобки.

```
string input = @"Protocol=(SNMP) Address=(\(test\))";

string pattern = @"(?<key>\w+) = \( (?<value>.+?) \) (?!\))";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["key"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["value"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Лучше проверяли бы именно отсутствие обратной косой. никто не мешает написать `addr=(abc\(test\)x\(y\)z)` тогда остается только проблема с проверкой экранирования самой обратной косой, но если у ТС в реальных данных этого быть не может, то на этом можно и остановится, что бы не перегружать регулярку

Answer (score 1):

Если формат строки точно определен (нет переменного количества пробелов, лишних символов до/перед `=`, `(`, `)` и т.п.), то можно обойтись и без регулярных выражений. По крайней мере, это даст прирост производительности.

```
var str = @"Protocol=(SNMP) Address=(\(test\))";
string[] values = str.Split(' ');

var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var v in values) {
    string[] pairs = v.Split('=');
    result[pairs[0]] = pairs[1].Substring(1, pairs[1].Length - 2);
}
```

Comment: Плюсую. Использование нескольких `string.Split` или `Regex.Split` зачастую оказывается самым простым способом.